# Dataframe is showing as nill

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
baseurl = "https://www.amazon.com/"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36", "Accept-language":"en-US, en;q=0.5'}
for x in range(1,75):
main_page = requests.get(f'https://www.amazon.in/books-for-1-year-old/s?k=books+for+1+year+old&i=stripbooks&rh=n%3A1318073031%2Cp_n_age_range%3A1318384031&page={x}', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page.content, 'lxml')
booklist = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'a-section a-spacing-none'})
#     print(booklist)

```
for book in booklist:
    reference = book.find_all('a',attrs = {'class': 'a-link-normal s-no-outline'}, href=True)
    for item in reference:
        link = baseurl+item['href']
        #print(link)
        webpage = requests.get(link, headers = headers)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "lxml")
        title_parent = soup2.find('span', attrs = {'id': 'productTitle'})
        if title_parent is not None:
            title = title_parent.text
            print(link)
            print(title)
            desc_parent1 = soup2.find('div', attrs = {'id': 'bookDescription_feature_div'})
            desc_parent2 = soup2.find('div', attrs = {'id': 'iframeContent'})
            if desc_parent1 is not None:
                desc = desc_parent1.find('div').text
            elif desc_parent1 is not None:
                desc = desc_parent2.find('div').text
            print(desc)

testlink = 'https://www.amazon.in/Wonder-House-Books/dp/9388369882/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?keywords=books+for+1+year+old&qid=1637501815&refinements=p_n_age_range%3A1318384031&s=books&sr=1-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFUVDk0RFk2WEpFTTAmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA2MTk3MDg3WUpXR0E2RzJXSCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNDY1NzE5M0xRQzE4TUhYUkQwSiZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU='
for book in booklist:
    
    r = requests.get(testlink, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    details = soup.find('ul', attrs = {'class':'a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical a-spacing-none detail-bullet-list'}).text.strip()
    print(details)
    book_data = {
        'links': ['link'],
        'title':['title'],
        'description':['desc_parent1'],
        'description2' : ['desc_parent2'] ,
        'deatils': ['details'],
    }
print(book_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(book_data)
print(df.head())
```

When i execute `print(book_data)`, I am getting the dictionary data as expected, but when it is tranformed into a dataframe with pandas it shows null. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Format the code properly and add the output of book_data.

Comment: I can not find anything wrong with the dictionary or panda code. In line with Himanshu, I would recommend formating the code more nicely and providing the output and error message.

Comment: Hey, @HimanshuPingulkar thank you for replying.

Comment: Publisher
                                    ‏
                                        :
                                    ‎
                                 Wonder House Books; First edition (1 January 2019); Prakash Books

Comment: Language
                                    ‏
                                        :
                                    ‎
                                 English   Board book
                                    ‏
                                        :
                                    ‎
                                 440 pages   ISBN-10
                                    ‏
                                        :
                                    ‎
                                 9388369882   ISBN-13
                                    ‏

Comment: ‎
                                 978-9388369886   Reading age
                                    ‏
                                        :
                      1 - 5 years   Item Weight:400 g   Dimensions:29.97 x 9.91 x 8.89 cm   Country of Origin:India   Import :011-23247062   Packer : Prakash Books   Generic Name:Books

Comment: I got output for all the books in the same format(didnt post the entire output because of the character constraint)


  links  title   description  description2  deatils    (row 1)
0  link  title  desc_parent1  desc_parent2  details   (row 2)

(This is the output for the dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

The scraping code seems to be working fine, the only problem is with the `book_data` dictionary variable. The variables link, title, etc does not work in the way you think it does, that is why you are getting a null dataframe as the dictionary variable is empty/wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

baseurl = "https://www.amazon.com/"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36", "Accept-language":"en-US, en;q=0.5'}

for x in range(1,75):
    main_page = requests.get(f'https://www.amazon.in/books-for-1-year-old/s?k=books+for+1+year+old&i=stripbooks&rh=n%3A1318073031%2Cp_n_age_range%3A1318384031&page={x}', headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page.content, 'lxml')
    booklist = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'a-section a-spacing-none'})
#     print(booklist)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['links', 'title', 'description'])

for book in booklist:
    reference = book.find_all('a',attrs = {'class': 'a-link-normal s-no-outline'}, href=True)
    for item in reference:
        link = baseurl+item['href']
        # print(link)
        webpage = requests.get(link, headers = headers)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "lxml")
        title_parent = soup2.find('span', attrs = {'id': 'productTitle'})
        if title_parent is not None:
            title = title_parent.text
            # print(link)
            # print(title)
            desc_parent1 = soup2.find('div', attrs = {'id': 'bookDescription_feature_div'})
            desc_parent2 = soup2.find('div', attrs = {'id': 'iframeContent'})
            if desc_parent1 is not None:
                desc = desc_parent1.find('div').text
            elif desc_parent1 is not None:
                desc = desc_parent2.find('div').text
            # print(desc)
        df.loc[len(df.index)] = [link, title, desc]

print(df.head())
```

Comment: Can you please tell me as to why isnt the dicitonary working? And the code you have provided isn't working for me till still gives me the same error as  : Empty DataFrame
Columns: [links, title, description]
Index: []

Comment: @LaxmiAgarwal This code works fine for me, the dataframe is being populated. What IDE are you using, how are you running the code? Try using Jupyter notebook or Google colab.

Comment: I'am using jupyter notebook. I have mentioned the link below of a screenshot of my code. Can you please look at it once and let me know as to where am i going wrong?

Comment: @LaxmiAgarwal As I told you before the problem is with `book_data` dict var. Also in the 1st `for` loop, you are storing the values in a single variable, so at the end of loop you only have 1 value in the variable(eg. link, title). Try converting these variables to list or dict.

Comment: Thank for your response . I will look into it again.